# Login to tfs online (vso) server 2003 and ie8

Tags: tfs, internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2003, azure-devops

Starting two weeks ago i cannot not login to vso using my account, i got this message

```
"VS400664: Sorry, we were unable to retrieve a configured identity provider for you to use when creating an account.  If the problem persists, check your web browser security settings.  You may need to add https://tfsprodch1acs01.accesscontrol.windows.net to your trusted zones.
Refresh"
```

Note that i can access using google chrome, but this error come just in internet explorer (8) or from visual studio when try to login,

when i try to browse to `https://tfsprodch1acs01.accesscontrol.windows.net` using IE i get "Internet explorer cannot display the webpage" but i can browse using chrome.

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant for programming questions. You may want to post this in the [Visual Studio Online MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=TFService).

Answer (score 1):

IE8 is not supported by VSO or TFS 2012+.

Comment: IE8 is indeed no longer supported by VSO (and hasn't been for more than a year). However, Windows Server 2003 is not relevant - depends only on the client, and we support a lot of clients (both browsers and older versions of VS even VB6 using the MSSCCI add-in).